# Changing chart colour C#

Tags: c#, charts

I have assignment for my college, I am trying to change the colour of bar when the value of the plant is less than 200 to red, if I use `(mainChart.Series[0].Color = Color.Red;)` it works but it changes the whole bar colour and I want only for the fist bar `(Point(0)` in  the example below I have 2 and if the any one can help please.

```
 int plant1 = 470;

int plant1 = 870;



 private void moislevel_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
               mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points.Clear();
               mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points.AddXY("plant1", plant1);
               mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points.AddXY("plant2", plant2);
            plant1 = plant1 - 20;
            plant2 = plant2 - 20;
        }


  if (plant1 <= 200) // if the plant value is under 200 then show the image that is red
{
                
                this.mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points[0].Color = Color.Red;

            }
            else if (plant1 > 200 && plant1 <= 550) 
            {                                       
              
                this.mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points[0].Color = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
               
                this.mainChart.Series["MoistureLevels"].Points[0].Color = Color.Green;
            };
```

Comment: welcome - what charting library?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287181/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-datapoint-label-based-on-the-chart-bar-size/51288564#51288564) example which colors the points while adding them. This is closer to your case, than writing a loop. Note how I get the index while adding the points and how I write the testing code a little shorter..

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the individual bars with the help of Templates in ASP.net Charts.
you have to import the file called `templatefile.xml` by adding this code in your page.

```
ChartObject.LoadTemplate("templatefile.xml");
```

You can get this `templatefile` for the seperate colors in this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8cfadcb-6853-4cff-8ffa-7488c13321b8/styling-a-chart?forum=aspdotnetwebpages).